# Why is Kehaar written with an accent?

Tags: richard-adams, watership-down

In *Watership Down* the bird [Kehaar](https://watershipdown.fandom.com/wiki/Kehaar) is written with an accent and poor grammar when talking with the rabbits. A representative excerpt:

> "Meester 'Azel, vat you do? You no stay 'ere?"
> "They're tired out, Kehaar. They've got to have a rest."
> "Ees not to rest 'ere. Ees rabbits come."
> "Yes, but not just yet. We can--"
> "Ya, ya, ees coming for find you! Ees close!"
> <sub>Conversation between Kehaar and Hazel from Chapter 32: Across the Iron Road</sub>

I can roughly make out what Kehaar means to say. However, it is more difficult to understand him as I have to mentally fix up spelling and grammar. I know he is speaking in the general hedgerow inter-species language, but Adams could have chosen to translate his speech into a more understandable form, or to simply give Kehaar less of an accent. So for what reason is Kehaar written with such an accent and poor grammar?

Comment: A question I'd often wondered, was whether Adams was attempting to imitate a specific accent.

Comment: @mikado That was already on [my to-ask list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=56292888#56292888), and now I've [gone ahead and posted it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16555/17).

Comment: @mikado and bobble - [who knew](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16567/17) there's a bunch of academic literature on this topic! :-)

Comment: When authors do this it is usually to indicate the "otherness" or "foreigness" of the character. From a rabbit's point of view a seagull is an exotic creature from a far off land. We would expect them to talk differently.

Comment: Could you expand that into an answer?