# Identification of Kehaar's accent

Tags: richard-adams, watership-down

In Richard Adams's novel *Watership Down*, the seagull character Kehaar is written with a distinctive accent unlike all other characters. Here's an example of a conversation between him and Hazel:

> "Meester Pigvig, 'e plenty good fella."
> "Yes, he is."
> "'E say you no getting mudders. Ees finish mudders. Plenty trouble for you."
> "Yes, that's true. We don't know what to do. No mothers anywhere."
> "Listen. I get peeg, fine plan. I go fine now. Ving, 'e better. Vind finish, den I fly. Fly for you. Find plenty mudders, tell you vere dey are, ya?"
> "Why, what a splendid idea, Kehaar! How clever of you to think of it! You very fine bird."
> "Ees finish mudders for me dis year. Ees too late. All mudders sitting on nest now. Eggs come."
> "I'm sorry."
> "Nudder time I get mudder. Now I fly for you."
> "We'll do everything we possibly can to help you."

**Is Kehaar's accent meant to represent, or inspired by, any particular human accent in English?** I always assumed it was Scandinavian, which would make sense if he came from across the North Sea, but the setting of the novel is closer to the English Channel, although this doesn't seem like a French accent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Kehaar's accent is based on a Norwegian one, and is consistent in itself.

In fact, Kehaar's accent and entire character are **based on a real Norwegian man** that Richard Adams knew. As he wrote himself (I haven't tracked down the primary source to check it myself, but the  secondary source [Douglas Leatherland, "The Capacities and Limitations of Language in Animal Fantasies", *Humanimalia* 11(2) (2020)](https://www.depauw.edu/humanimalia/issue%2022/leatherland.html) seems reliable):

> Kehaar’s character, even his voice, is based on a Norwegian Resistance man I knew in the war, a splendid chap, Johansen
>
> <sub>-- Richard Adams, “To the Order of Two Little Girls: The Oral and Written Versions of *Watership Down*”, in Charlotte F. Otten and Gary D. Schmidt, eds., *The Voice of the Narrator in Children’s Literature: Insights from Writers and Critics*, Greenwood Press, 1989</sub>

Furthermore, an exhaustive linguistic analysis of the entire text of everything Kehaar says in the novel (a total of 250 "sentences", of which 182 are simple in structure, 38 are compound, and 31 have complex structure, with an off-by-one error somewhere and the overall mean sentence length being 5.1 words) has been conducted in a paper published in the [RELC Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELC_Journal), with the conclusion that **Kehaar's "language" has a linguistically consistent style**:

> On first reading the book it struck me that Kehaar’s speech was very regular and exhibited features clearly similar to pidgins and other ’simplified’ or ’reduced’ codes. There was furthermore a large enough corpus to make generalizations about the language with some confidence, and yet it was not too large to deal with exhaustively. Ferguson (1971) refers to what he calls a "register of simplified speech" which has been "little studied" although it seems quite widespread and may even be universal. This he calls "Foreigner Talk." [...]
>
> The language of Kehaar exhibits every one of these listed features together with a number of others. It is for this reason that a closer analysis was undertaken. I believe that in it we may have a good example of the register of foreigner-talk in English and that its occurrence in a popular book for children is evidence of how this reduced code could be learned in our culture. [...]
>
> Although there are many more potentially interesting features of Kehaar’s language not dealt with here, enough has been said, I hope, to show the astonishing degree of regularity and consistency in its grammatical features which this text exhibits. It goes well beyond merely a ‘tendency’ (in Ferguson’s term) to certain processes of simplification. With the exception of the few ’idiosyncratic’ sentences which even an uncritical reading reveals, the grammar is solidly systematic. This can be explained in two ways: either the author is a sophisticated linguist capable of consciously applying a series of reduction rules to the standard grammar, or else he is working intuitively with an ’internalised’ grammer *[sic]* of ’foreigner-talk’. If the former, one may ask: why choose one set of reduction processes rather than another? From a purely linguistic point of view the decision must be arbitrary. However, as an author wishing to communicate effectively - particularly with a children’s audience - he must hit upon just those ’reduction rules’ which will not interfere with his readers’ ability to interpret the text. These must therefore be of the sort found in other registers of the language known to and used by his readership; i.e. they must be conventional in the community.
>
> <sub>-- [S. Pit Corder, "The language of Kehaar", *RELC Journal* 8(1) (1977), pp. 1-12](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/003368827700800101?journalCode=rela)</sub>

Who knew that there'd be multiple published academic papers about the accent of a seagull in a novel about rabbits!